# How to select first, last and previous and next via sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create pagination of records from a sql statement, I was able to get next and previous for all but the last record shows the previous record as next due to the sql query only returning 1 row instead of 2. I am setting next based on the first result and previous as the second result.

The data:

- Apple
- Banana
- Grape
- Orange

The sql:

```
select * 
from (select top 1 fruit 
      FROM table 
      where fruit > 'Banana' 
      order by fruit asc) as x 

UNION ALL 

select * 
from (select top 1 fruit 
      FROM table 
      where fruit < 'Banana' order by fruit desc) as y
```

The result:

```
fruit
--------
Grape
Apple
```

This works great!

For the first record - I get the correct result for the first record being the true next.
For the last record - I get one result which is the second query that gets the previous record. However I have no way of knowing its the last record so it outputs as Next instead of Previous.

How would I determine that is the last record and the single row being returned is actually the previous?

OR

How can I have the query return a NULL row for the Next query? So I can test against a NULL result?

BONUS POINTS!

How can I have one query that will give me first record, last record and next and previous so I could enable circular pagination? If on first record show last record as previous. If on last record show next record as first record?

Comment: If you want to have "first", "last", "next" etc., you need some column to **order by**, e.g. a *sequence number* or something - and then you need to specify that `ORDER BY` clause in your select statement. No `ORDER BY` --> no ordering of any kind, and you cannot define a *next* or *previous* without ordering.

Comment: Next should *(as you have)* be `WHERE fruit > 'banana' ORDER BY fruit ASC`. But your Previous definition should be `WHERE fruit < 'banana' ORDER BY fruit DESC`. *(With `>` changed to `<`. Or, is that jus a typo in the question?)* Also, to get `NULL`, try using `MAX(fruit)` and `MIN(fruit)` instead of using `TOP 1` with `ORDER BY`.

Comment: I fixed the typo @Dems I will try the MAX/MIN.

Comment: @marc_s I am basing the ordering on A-Z the list is an alphabetical that the user can page through each item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    MIN(fruit)   as first,
    MAX(fruit)   as previous
  FROM
    yourTable
  WHERE
    fruit < 'banana'
)
CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT
    MIN(fruit)   as next,
    MAX(fruit)   as last
  FROM
    yourTable
  WHERE
    fruit > 'banana'
)
```

Or, shorter, but I'm not sure that it would be more performant...

```
SELECT
  MIN(CASE WHEN fruit < 'banana' THEN fruit END)   as first,
  MAX(CASE WHEN fruit < 'banana' THEN fruit END)   as previous,
  MIN(CASE WHEN fruit > 'banana' THEN fruit END)   as next,
  MAX(CASE WHEN fruit > 'banana' THEN fruit END)   as last
FROM
  yourTable
```

Or, as a final wierd option...

```
SELECT
  (SELECT TOP 1 fruit FROM yourTable WHERE fruit < 'banana' ORDER by fruit ASC)  AS first,
  (SELECT TOP 1 fruit FROM yourTable WHERE fruit < 'banana' ORDER by fruit DESC) AS previous,
  (SELECT TOP 1 fruit FROM yourTable WHERE fruit > 'banana' ORDER by fruit ASC)  AS next,
  (SELECT TOP 1 fruit FROM yourTable WHERE fruit > 'banana' ORDER by fruit DESC) AS last
```

*(This may be usefull if you have thousands+ of records, as each is search quickly and separately.)*

Comment: THANK YOU! I appreciate the guidance.